# Understanding available frequencies of quartz crystal from datasheet

Tags: datasheet, crystal

I would like to make an order of crystals from digikey.com. The crystal product series datasheet is at https://support.epson.biz/td/api/doc_check.php?dl=brief_C-2-TYPE_en.pdf

However, I am having hard time to read the data sheet.

I know the crystal has series resonant frequency and parallel resonant frequency.

My targeting frequency should be between them for LC tank circuit.

Here is my question.

I saw the nominal frequency ranges in data sheet.

For example, nominal frequency range : 20 kHz to 120 kHz.

The targeting frequency is 100 kHz.

Then, Is 20 kHz the series resonant frequency?

I would like to know the information of series resonant frequency from data sheet.

Thanks.

Comment: The datasheet you forgot to link to?

Comment: https://support.epson.biz/td/api/doc_check.php?dl=brief_C-2-TYPE_en.pdf

Comment: www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/epson/C-2-100.0000K-P:PBFREE/SER3333-ND/1022118

Answer (score 2):

For the C-2 and C-4 types, the datasheet says "Please contact us about available frequencies."

I take this to mean that crystals are available for various frequencies in that range (and they may be able to make crystals for other frequencies on request).

You should, therefore, discuss your particular requirements with one of the company's application engineers.

Comment: It is not a _may_, for crystals of this type the design is what determines the frequency.

Comment: @placeholder: I said "may", thinking that the company may not be willing to make custom frequency crystals, although the lack of a list of standard frequencies in the datasheet may imply that they do do custom frequencies.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Btw, I am confused....Is my targeting frequency the series resonance or between series and parallel resonance. I thank it is between series and parallel resonance.

Comment: The region between series and parallel resonance is inductive, so it is parallel with Cload to make LC tank. This is what I want to design.

Comment: @Peter Bennett placeholder

Answer (score 0):

The data sheet says that the Epson C-Type can be made in the range of 20 kHz～120 kHz.  32.768 kHz is a standard frequency (a very common clock frequency), but the product can be custom built over the 20 kHz～120 kHz range.  Apparently DigiKey sells 100 KHz as a standard, stocked product.  This may not be as complicated as you fear.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means ask Epson to cut a crystal to give your specified frequency in this range. Cutting crystals to specific custom frequencies is not unusual, for some suppliers it is a normal part of their business, so they are tooled up for small custom orders.

If your order is too small to be interesting to Epson, you have two alternatives

- settle for one of their limited range of stock frequencies (in addition to 100kHz, I have seen 60kHz for radio controlled clocks from a UK supplier
- find a local supplier of crystals who will undertake a smaller order. Even one-off orders may not be as expensive as you might expect.

To clarify another point, at these frequencies, the series and parallel resonances will only be a few Hz apart. Another part of specifying your crystal is specifying which resonance is to be on your nominal frequency, and if it's the series resonance, you specify the load capacitance, as the series resonance varies (slightly) with capacitance.